# Truncating decimal digits like Excel in python

Tags: python, excel, floating-point, decimal, floating-accuracy

In my excel file, I've some calculations. Calculation returns 0,345 and excel convert it to 0,35. I made it in python. Python is returning 0,345, but I want to take 0,35 like Excel. I've tried with round() method, but it's returning 0.34.

```
calc = round(value * arg / 1000, 5)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Floating point numbers are inherently imprecise. Where `n` is the number of digits to round to, multiply by 10<sup>n</sup>, add 0.5, round, then divide by 10<sup>n</sup>.

```
>>> number = 0.345
>>> round(number * 10 ** 2 + 0.5) / 10 ** 2
0.35
```